# Documenting methods created with meta-programming using YARD

Tags: ruby, documentation, metaprogramming, yard

I'm currently working on a gem and writing documentation for it. I currently have a class that has several method defined using `defined_method` as follows:

```
class Client
  ['one', 'two'].each do |method_name|
    # Sets the value
    # @param argument the argument to set.
    define_method("set_#{method_name}") do |argument|
      # Method content
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to document these methods using YARD, but when generating the documentation of the project, theses methods do not appear in the class documentation.

Does anyone know how I could document these? Am I missing something?

Comment: not  a yard expert, but having looked at their docs i dont think there's a way to do this other than writing a freeform comment. Besides, if the methods are truly dynamic, you won't be able to document them accurately. If you want to document `one` and `two` methods, make them their own methods. Save `define_method` for when it's needed.

Comment: The actual methods are not exactly as the example above but I see your point about freeform comment.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating an arbitrary list, you would generally use macros to define the methods by wrapping the dynamic behaviour into a class method that can be documented as DSL-style calls in your class:

```
  class << self
    private
    # @macro [attach] container.increment
    #   @method $1()
    #   Increment the $1 container.
    def make(name)
      define_method(name) { container.send(name).increment }
    end
  end

  make :lion
  make :pigeon
end
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you